# Passing variable in several js files using Cypress

Tags: javascript, global-variables, cypress

For Cypress tests I am setting up an email adress in a js file. Then I would like to use this variable in another file. With import/export it runs the entire script from the previous file, I only need the variable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your email value to `/cypress/support/index.js` and import into both tests.

Or define a custom command in `/cypress/support/commands.js` and avoid having to import it.

```js
// cypress/support/commands.js

Cypress.Commands.add('getEmail', () => 'random@gmail.com')
```

```js
// all tests

cy.getEmail().then(email => {
  ...
})
```

Unfortunately that makes a simple variable asynchronous and you have to access it with `.then()`.

---

**Environment variables for static data**

If the data is static, you can define it as an environment variable,

In Cypress V9

```js
// cypress.json

{
  ...
  "env": {
    "email": "random@gmail.com",
  }
}
```

In Cypress V10

```js
// cypress.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: '128076ed-9868-4e98-9cef-98dd8b705d75',
  env: {
    email: 'random@gmail.com',
  }
})
```

```js
// all tests
const email = Cypress.env('email')
```

---

Actually, in **Cypress v10** the config is now a javascript file so you should be able to set `email` via a function

```js
// cypress.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: '128076ed-9868-4e98-9cef-98dd8b705d75',
  env: {
    getEmail: () => { 
      return 'random@gmail.com';
    },
  }
})
```

```js
// all tests
const email = Cypress.env('getEmail')()  // invoke the function
```

Comment: thanks for the extensive reply, I have also researched fixtures, will add to this post another possible solution with a dynamic variable

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#description) to avoid running the tests in the exporting file.

```js
export const email = ...
```

```js
import {email} from ...
```

Comment: thanks ! this is indeed what i have implemented but when I run the test in file 2 it starts running file 1 first. File 1: export const email ='random@gmail.com'; File 2: import { email } from './cyCompRegFlowTestenvironment';

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using Fixtures:

support/commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generateFixtureEmail', () => {

cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/email.json', {
    'hits':Cypress._.times(1, () => {
        let randomNumber= Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
        const email ='random+'+randomNumber+'@mail.com';
        return {
            'Email': email

        }
    })
})
```

a json file is made: fixtures/email.json

```
"hits": [
{
  "Email": "random+475@mail.com"
}
```

]

support/index.d.ts:

```
declare namespace Cypress {
interface Chainable<Subject = string> {
    generateFixtureEmail(): Chainable<Element>;
}
```

integration/test-scripts/test.js:

```
describe('Test', function()
  {
         before(() => {
            cy.generateFixtureEmail()

            cy.fixture('email').then(function (data) {
                this.data = data;
                 })

                       })


    it('testcase 1', function () { cy.loginWithEmail(this.data.hits[0].Email)
```

note: do not commit the generated json file